# Commerce Recurring framework with customizable products

Tags: commerce

I understand that one of the field's from the recurring framework need to be part of the product and by extension a rule needs that to create a recurring entity by getting the products that have recurring field in them.

I had added the recurring field in the line items types that are of the type add to cart, so that the customer can pick what kind of recurrence they want instead of adding it to the product. These type of fields do not get picked by the Get Recurring Product action in the rules and no recurring entity is created.

Any advice on how to make this work so customers can decide the period rather than the store providing different subscription options by creating that many products?

Answer (score 0):

Make a version of the product for each period:

- Toothbrush (Monthly)
- Toothbrush (Quarterly)
- Toothbrush (Bi-annual)

etc.

Then, add each of those products to the product reference. Your customer will then be able to choose which subscription they want.

Comment: That process I am already aware of.  Where this needs to go is to reduce the effort to create as many products as subscription options.  Imagine a use case where there are thousands of subscription products this would be very ineffective to build 4 to 5 products around them with varying subscription duration.  Customizable products are efficient in that regard.  So how to integrate that with recurring entities.  Can rules be used.

Comment: Then you might want to consider generating the products automatically. There are ways to use Rules to automatically duplicate products or you could just handle it via feeds.

Comment: That is another spin on the same, and it does improve it.  What I am looking for is to be able to give that control back the customer so they decide by simply typing in the add to cart form using customizable product instead of going down a list of monthly options.

Comment: I might be wrong, but if I remember correctly, Commerce Recurring needed an interval field to work. There was an effort at one time to allow for arbitrary dates to determine when an order recurred and if you had that then you wouldn't be too far off from what you want.

Comment: The part that I am not understanding, is that Commerce Customizable Products works off of line item types, and I am dropping in all the interval fields related to creating a recurring product in the line item types with add to cart form.  And when customer is choosing these options why does the rule for creating a recurring entity not working.

Comment: I might try Commerce License.  I am not sure how that works and if I can drop commerce license field in to Customizable product or line items types that user can choose.  Will post back if I have any success with that.